# NGerman babel does not work

Tags: babel, languages, german

I need a bit of help with LateX as I am not the best.
So the problem which I currently have is that the babel package [ngerman] does not work. The English works but I need the German one to work and I just cannot figure out why. [image]

Thanks for your help

Sorry for coming back so late -
The code is not the nicest ... sorry about that but I am no programmer

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  chapterprefix,
  egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles% no sans serif headings etc.
  ]{scrreprt} % for bigger size of text 
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{newtxtext}% <- changed
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %help: usepackage[ngerman]{babel} does not work ... \enquote: commas should be at the bottom in the beginning, not the top - not running - error line
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{csquotes} %enquote
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym} %smiley
\usepackage{tabularx} % table x for certain width

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{1mm} %fußnoten abstand 
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 %footnote won't run on two pages
\usepackage{footmisc} %footnotes indent 
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{\parindent}  %footnotes indent 

\newenvironment{hanging}[1][2em]{%  %Literaturverzeichnis
  \addmargin[#1]{0pt}\setlength{\parindent}{-#1}\hspace*{-#1}% 
  \ignorespaces 
}{% 
  \endaddmargin 
} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}% only parts and chapters should be numbered

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}% headings of section, subsection etc. should not be bold

%chapter in toc and on page (numbering)
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\bfseries\large,% does the same as \setkomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\large}
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}% center chapter headings
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:\enskip} 

\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}#1\autodot}{#2}}%
}

% section
\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\sffamily\Large]{section}% does the same as \setkomafont{section}{\sffamily\Large}
% subsection
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %indent=1em,% <- add this if the subsections should be indented
  font=\itshape% changes the font, does the same as \setkomafont{subsection}{\itshape}
]{subsection}

% format headings with style=section, eg. section, subsection and subsubsection
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\centering #3#4}% centers section headings
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
}

% use page style empty in in ToC, LoF and LoT
\AfterTOCHead{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}

% rename LoF and LoT
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listtablename}{Tables}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: it is ngerman not nGerman.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Hi, just tried the ngerman and it is still not running ...
! Package scrbase Error: `\listfigurename' not defined at language `english'.

See the scrbase package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.86 \begin{document}
                     
?

Comment: Between what you post and the `\begin{document}` on line 86 there are 50 lines of code where things could be going wrong. Please post a minimal code reproducing the issue, and post it as *text*, not as snapshot.

Comment: I reposted. I haven't been able to figure out the mistake in the past few days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the combination

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
[...]
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listtablename}{Tables}
```

You are loading `babel` with the `ngerman` option, meaning that the language `english` isn't defined. When you do

```
\renewcaptionname{english}{...}{...}
```

then you'll get the error.

If you are writing simply a German text then remove the two `\renewcaptionname` instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, install the package:

```
$ sudo apt -y install texlive-lang-german
```

Solution is from [here](https://techoverflow.net/2019/05/31/how-to-fix-latex-error-package-babel-error-unknown-option-ngerman-on-ubuntu/)